# ConTeXt: number empty lines

Tags: context, verbatim, line-numbering

This source:

```
\starttext
  \startlinenumbering
    \starttyping
      int x;

      int y;
    \stoptyping
  \stoplinenumbering
\stoptext
```

Renders like this:

```
1       int x;

2       int y;
```

How can I make it number the empty line?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why `linenumbering` and `typing` don't play nice together, but if you just want display-style verbatim to be numbered you can set up the `typing` environment to do that itself:

```
\setuptyping[numbering=line]
\starttext
  \starttyping
    int x;

    int y;
  \stoptyping
\stoptext
```

produces the following.

```
1       int x;
2
3       int y;
```

Comment: This only numbers the first line for me.

Comment: @flyx That's odd. This works for me on the version of ConTeXt that shipped with TeX Live 2017, and a more recent Minimals version.

Comment: I am still on Tex Live 2016 for various reasons. However, it would be strange if this only worked with the most recent version.

Comment: @flyx I don't have an older version on my machine to test. But I just tried it on `contextgarden`, which reports its version as mid 2016, and it only numbers the first line too.

Comment: Okay, I'll see whether I have the possibility to update to TeX Live 2017 and report back.

Comment: @flyx: If you don't want to update Tex Live, you can install ConTeXt standalone in a parallel directory without interfering with TL.

Comment: @flyx I went through the ConTeXt source to find why it's not working in TL 2016.  Unfortunately, the change is on the Lua level, so it's not easy to backport the fix.  You'd have to edit the core files and rebuild the format.  Therefore I also advise you to either update TL or use Standalone (I recommend Standalone, the TL 2017 snapshot of ConTeXt was a bit broken).

Comment: If you `usemodule [vim]` with it's `numbering=yes` option, you will get line numbers for blank lines. See [http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules/t-vim](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules/t-vim).